# Catch dynamic URL in jQuery when using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, url

I am trying to catch a dynamic URL in jQUery. Normally I can catch the path and then load it like so:

```
    $('a').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        $('#Div2').load(pathname+'question/');
    });
```

However, the path that I am attempting to catch is loaded into the main page via Ajax so the URL that I capture belongs to the main page rather than the loaded page.

The URL it catches: localhost/home/

The URL I am attempting to catch: localhost/home/loaded_page

Any thoughts on how I can capture the path for the loaded page? its dynamic (home/1, home/2, etc) so I can't just type in the full URL

Comment: May I ask why you are not using https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax ?

Comment: Haven't discovered this previously. I'll give it a try. Is there a way to do it via the .load() method that you know of?

Comment: The PJAX module will change the location accordingly, so you will not have this problem. I would stick to this module and avoid reinventing the wheel.